# How to search for best match in PHP (searching with tolerance)

Tags: php, arrays, json, search, steam-web-api

I need to search an array for a name to get an id.
 So far it looks like this:

```
<?php
$name = "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive";  //Input name

$url = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0002/?format=json'; //API JSON file

$content = file_get_contents($url) ; // Retrieve the JSON data string from the website
$data = json_decode($content, true); // Convert the JSON string into PHP array 

$key = array_search($name, array_column($data['applist']['apps'], 'name')); //Search

echo $data['applist']['apps'][$key]['appid']; // Echoes ID - 730 in this case
?>
```

Right now I am using **array_search** to do the searchig however that would not work with unprecise answers.
For example if **$name** was **"counter strike global offensive"** (notice the removed symbols) it would return null because there is no such input in that JSON file.
 Is there a way give the search a little tolerance and maybe make it ignore case sensitivity?

Comment: Does the API offer search functionality? That might be easier than doing a full-text search in PHP. Don't get me wrong, you can definitely do it with PHP but if the API offers that functionality out of the box, I'd go with that.

Comment: Hmm - apparently they don't offer a search https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/ISteamApps#GetAppList. `This call has no additional parameters.` I guess you should start by defining what your search should look like. Should it be case senstitive, ignore non-alpha characters, what about spaces, partial matches, etc.

Comment: The way is: write the code to handle this, if the API does not provide such search capabilities

Comment: I would definitely want to code this however I don't really know where to start. I tried google but the best thing I found was array_search.